# Can you "bump into" something that's on the internet?

Tags: idiom-request

Let's say you're talking to a friend, and he's telling you that Facebook is giving out promotional codes for the iPhone Xs Plus for select users. Can you reply to your friend saying **"Do you know anyone who's bumped into the promo code yet?"**

Answer (score 4):

Your phrase

> **bumped into**

may have the meaning

> **serendipitously ran into**
>   **unexpectedly met**

as in

> I unexpectedly **bumped into** John at the concert, he was there with his family.

in your case, you seem to mean

> **come across**
>   
>  
>   I **bumped into** the promo code.
>   *I* ***came across*** *the promo code.*
>   *I* ***stumbled onto*** *the promo code.*

Your phrase usually has a physical meaning and native speakers would not use it the way you are, but you could us it in your context and people would still understand

Comment: We might also say “I stumbled on this promo code.” https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stumble+on